# application rejected from Google play "Need login credentials for app review"

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

I upload my application to google play first time I forgot to sent login credentials so application rejected.
but I updated application and send credentials in 'app-content' section in google console.
I receive e-mail that say application rejected for the same reason and attached screenshot for login page with credentials which I sent in 'app-content' but they didn't tell me what is the problem exactly so I don't understand how can I fix my application to be approved.
this is e-mail and screenshot which I received
[image: E-mail body]

[image: This is screenshot]

anyone can help me in that ?

**Edit**
these credentials are correct I tested it more than one time